# Should I use transformer + op-amp or only op-amp to amplify small audio signal?

Tags: amplifier, transformer, audio

I am trying to amplify a 10uV audio signal.  This is easy enough with an op-amp, except that I need to make sure Vos is much smaller than the signal.  10uV is doable, but if I want to amplify much smaller signals it's going to get tricky.

Would it be better (or at least acceptable) to use a transformer to boost the input voltage before feeding this into an op-amp where I didn't have to worry about the offset voltage?  Are there any general rules when it might be preferable to use a transformer vs. an op-amp for voltage amplification?  Is there some other trick involved for amplifying even smaller signals?

Comment: Since when audio is amplified by transformers anyway? I guess that is possible but then you are changing the impedance and impedance also affects the noise. What audio is coming at 10uV and why is Vos a problem since DC must anyway be ignored and filtered out?

Comment: Why not just make sure that the opamp response rolls off at DC? That's how it's usually handled.

Comment: A 10uV audio signal is 1000 times less than a reasonable microphone level (10mV). 10uV is -60dB from the 10mV reasonable mic level. Why is it so low?

Comment: This is the output from a little electret to a fairly low sound... After reading comments however I realized that even with a high gain the Vos doesn't really explode, so I can just filter out the DC offset.

Comment: @broken.eggshell You should have written at the outset that this is an electret and provided a link to its datasheet and some idea of the SPL you are dealing with.